# Festival 2.5 and multisyn JMK voice from 1.95

Tags: linux, voice, speech, festival

I have an old old linux 2.6 VM that I keep around just for Festival 1.95 and the JMK Multisyn voice. Try as I might to get multisyn working, I have not had any success on my Ubuntu 18.04 setup. I can't get Festival 1.95 working, and when I copy in the old jmk multisyn voice, I get the error below. I do have the jmk cg voice, but it feels 'flat' compared to the voice that we've been using for over a decade.

I've feel trying things for weeks, with no luck. Hopefully someone might have some advice or suggestions!

```
Copyright (C) University of Edinburgh, 1996-2010. All rights reserved.

clunits: Copyright (C) University of Edinburgh and CMU 1997-2010
clustergen_engine: Copyright (C) Carnegie Mellon University 2005-2017
hts_engine: 
The HMM-Based Speech Synthesis Engine "hts_engine API"
hts_engine API version 1.07 (http://hts-engine.sourceforge.net/)
Copyright (C) The HMM-Based Speech Synthesis Engine "hts_engine API"
Version 1.07 (http://hts-engine.sourceforge.net/)
Copyright (C) 2001-2012 Nagoya Institute of Technology
              2001-2008 Tokyo Institute of Technology
All rights reserved.

All rights reserved.
For details type `(festival_warranty)'
festival> (voice.list)
(cstr_us_jmk_arctic_multisyn cmu_us_jmk_cg kal_diphone)
festival> (voice_cstr_us_jmk_arctic_multisyn)
SIOD ERROR: unbound variable : voice_jmk_multisyn_configure_pre
festival> (quit)
```